# C# Collection Initializer not honored in an object initializer

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization, overriding, braces

Why isn't a collection initializer honored in an object initializer?

```
   public class Foo
   {
        public string[] Bar { get; set; }

        public Foo() { }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new Foo()
            {
                Bar = { }
            };

            Assert.Null(foo.Bar); // Null not empty...what gives?

        }
    }
```

The expectation is that the underlying array will be set to an initialized empty collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That way of initializing a new collection is rewritten internally as `Bar.Add()` for each element, and since you aren't adding anything to it it will not generate any calls to `.Add()`.

If you decompile that it will look like this (notice how the initialization is lost).

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Foo();
}
```

You can try by actually adding a string to your initialization. It won't compile but show the error below.

```cs
var foo = new Foo()
{
    Bar = { "" }
};
```

```
error CS1061: 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Now if you initialize it with a new array it will of course work.

```cs
var foo = new Foo()
{
    Bar = new[] { "" }
};
```

Checking this dempiled yields this.

```cs
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    string[] array = new string[1];
    array[0] = "";
    foo.Bar = array;
}
```

So in short, initialize your array in your class constructor to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `default(string[])` is `null`. You must initialize it, and you could use a constructor for it:

```
public class Foo
{
   public string[] Bar { get; set; }
   public Foo() 
   {
       Bar = new string[0];
   }
}
```

In this case, it will instance a new empty array on `Bar` property.

Answer (score 0):

If a collection initializer is used as part of a member initializer, a new collection will not be instantiated. It is simply syntactic sugar for calling the `Add(...)` method on the collection.

Note that in this (slightly modified) example, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public List<string> Bar { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo()
    {
        Bar = { "hello" }
    };
}
```

The C# spec defines this behaviour in section 7.6.10.2:

> A member initializer that specifies a collection initializer after the equals sign is an initialization of an embedded collection. **Instead of assigning a new collection to the field or property, the elements given in the initializer are added to the collection referenced by the field or property.**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you declaring an array this way, you may do what @Felipe Oriani mentioned but I assume you know that and you just trying to understand why your way is not working as it should work. So I will try relate to this and not the best practices of the way of declaring an array.

That's an interesting question as I found some weird things while trying to understand why it happens.

I noticed that if I am initializing it in the constructor with braces, it won't compile (`invalid expression term '{'`). Not sure why it doesn't compile and the other ways do compile?!

```
public Foo()
{
    Bar = { };
}
```

Then I mentioned that if I am declaring it not inside an object it works well:

```
string[] bar = { }; // Creates an empty array of strings
```

So it would be possible to do it and it will work as you expects:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string[] Bar { get; set; }

    public Foo(string[] bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] bar = { };
        var foo = new Foo(bar); // foo.Bar is not empty string array
    }
}
```